# What values are available for fn and fb options to the xterm command?

Tags: xterm

I am visually impaired and have difficulty with the current settings (9x15 and 9x15bold) which my script is specifying.  I would like to enlarge the fonts; how do I determine which values are possible for the fn and fb options?

In other words, I know that xterm is invoked like this: `xterm -fn 9x15 -fb 9x15bold ...`

I would like to increase the font size, but do not know how to determine what options are available nor how to (perhaps) increase the options available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X server finds its fonts along its "FontPath". If you do a `grep -A 7 FontPath /var/log/Xorg.0.log` you'll see directories with fonts files in them.

Take a look at [this link](http://ubuntumanual.org/posts/433/vinux-ubunu-linux-for-the-visually-impaired),

and [Big-X cursor](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/docs/HOWTO/X-Big-Cursor)

and the [Font HOW-TO](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/docs/HOWTO/Font-HOWTO)

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I continue my journey now...  Since posting the question, I have a few more... Hopefully these resources will help.

Comment: although your answer may have been really helpful for the OP, it doesn't answer the question about possible parameters using xterm with it's option -fn and -fb